# Send parameters via fetch to Python view for Stripe checkout

Tags: python, reactjs, stripe-payments

I have a Stripe endpoint set up in Python, looks like this:

```
def create_checkout_session(request):

donation_amount = request.POST['donationAmount']
donation_name = request.POST['donationName']

try:
    checkout_session = stripe.checkout.Session.create(
        line_items=[
            {
                'price_data': {
                    'unit_amount': donation_amount,
                    'currency': 'usd',
                    'product_data': {
                    'name': donation_name
                    },
                 },
                 'quantity': 1,
            },
        ],
        mode='payment',
        success_url=settings.DONATION_URL + '?success=true',
        cancel_url=settings.DONATION_URL + '?canceled=true',
    )
except Exception as e:
    return str(e)

return redirect(checkout_session.url, code=303)
```

And I'm trying to send the donationAmount and donationName via a fetch function.

```
const goToCheckout = (donation, userHandle) => {
    const donationName = "Donated by @" + userHandle;
    fetch(url, {
      method: "POST",
      body: {
        donationAmount: donation,
        donationName: donationName,
      },
    })
      .then(??)
      .catch((e) => {
        console.log(e);
      });
  };
```

What's the correct way of sending the parameters and opening the Stripe checkout page with the custom data I'm sending?

Comment: That code looks like it could work. I'd like to know a bit more about the issues you are running in to here. Is the server receiving these values properly? Is the redirect happening? Are there any errors you are receiving when trying to make these calls?

Comment: As this is your server, you can choose that happens in the ?? part of your then clause. A common pattern here is to have your server send back json with {"error": "some error message"} if you run in to an exception there and checking if you got an error code in your client side code.